# Post form data then render new template

Tags: html, django, forms, post

So I have a form in my HTML that looks like this:

```
<form id="passer" method="POST" action="{% url 'Sizer:printView' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="hidden" id="vals">
    <input type="submit" value="Print all selected items" id="printBut">
</form>
```

With this form what I wish to achieve is when the submit button is clicked my jQuery will calculate a value and put it into the vals field in the form, then I want it to post to the printView view (to get the calculated data into a view) then once the data has been post render a new template and pass in the data calculated by the jQuery.

My printView (where the data is being posted) looks like this:

```
def printView(request):
    to_print = str(request.POST.get('vals'))
    template = "Sizer/printview.html"
    context = {'to_print':to_print}
    return redirect('requested_print_data', to_print)
```

And my requested_print_data view (where I want to render my new template) looks like this:

```
def requested_print_data(request):
    all_data['to_print'] =       #Dont know how to get my variable 

    template = "Sizer/printdata.html"
    context = {'all_data':all_data}
    return render(request, template, context)
```

So at the moment what happens is when the form is submit, the value is calculated and stored into the form, the URL will gain the extra part from where it's being posted (www.example.com/printables  ---On Submit---> www.example.com/printables/printview/) but the template will remain the same.

I have been stuck on this for a day or two now so any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: jQuery as requested:

```
$('#passer').submit(function(){
    console.log("Inside click");
    var selected = [];
    var $vals = "";
    $('.datatable').find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function(){
            selected.push($(this).attr('value'));
    });
    $.each(selected, function(index, val){
        $vals+= val + ',';
    });
    console.log($vals)

    $("#vals").val($vals)
```

Comment: You should read this whole page https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/. Also, if you want to get the posted data in another view, you will need either a model or store it in session and retrieve it in the next view.

Comment: @cdvv7788 Thank you, I will read through now. It doesn't have to go to another view, my goal it to get the data calculated by the jQuery into another template so I can render some data with it. I was told it's possible without models and sessions (which is what I wanted to avoid)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can render the out put in the printView itself. No need to write another view. Change your printView to

```
def printView(request):
    to_print = str(request.POST.get('vals'))
    template = "Sizer/printdata.html"
    context = {'all_data':to_print}
    return render(request, template, context)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, however this doesn't solve my issue. I am still getting the URL changed (to the correct one) but it loads the same template and ignores the template declared in the view.

Comment: @J.Scull can you paste your jquery code that you used, why because if the data is  posted to new view correctly and as I have changed the template, it should render new data correctly if `Sizer/printdata.html` and `Sizer/printview.html` are different.

Comment: Added the jQuery to the question

Comment: What is the purpose of printView view? I can see that view is not doing any new functionality, it is just returning the posted data to new requested_print_data.

Comment: A user told me to submit it to a view, then redirect to another view and render the template from there. I didn't agree but I have followed. I dont mind scraping the other function as long as my requirement of getting the data calculated in the jQuery into the printdata.html template is met!

Comment: Something worth noting is that I have a print on the first line of printView() and this is not output to the console. However I do get a 'POST /heatsize/printables/printview/ HTTP/1.1' 200

Comment: can you check printing your POST data if it is sending the form data to view correctly or not?

Comment: I added a 'print(request.POST)' to the view but this doesnt not get output into the console either.

Comment: Thank you for your help, stupidly the issue was I missed a $ at the end of the printView URL. Adding this meant I could reach URLs that extended from /printview/ and therefore the code you gave me worked :)